# Multi-threaded UDP chat application in Java giving java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am trying to implement a chat application in Java using UDP for multiple clients. I used thread to accept input on server side and another thread to handle the input as well. My code is:

Server side:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ChatServer
{
    static DatagramSocket socket;
    static DatagramPacket packet;
    static ArrayList<InetAddress> arrayList;
    static LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> messages;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        arrayList = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

        messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

        byte[] b = new byte[500];

        System.out.println("Server initialized..");


        socket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        packet = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);

        Thread acceptorThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        System.out.println("acceptor");
                        if(arrayList.add(packet.getAddress()))
                            System.out.println("listtrue");


                        if(messages.add(packet.getData()))
                        System.out.println("queuetrue");;
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        };


        acceptorThread.start();

        Thread messageHandler = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                System.out.println("handler");
                while(true)
                {
                    if(messages.poll() != null)

                    {
                        byte []b = "soham".getBytes();
                        sendAll(b);
                    }

                }
            }
        };


        messageHandler.start();

    }   




    public static void sendAll(byte[] b)
    {
        for(InetAddress address : arrayList)
        {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, address, 4445);
            try 
            {
                socket.send(packet);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

and the client side is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        while(true)
        {
        //get input
        System.out.println("Message:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = sc.next();

            // get a datagram socket
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

            // send request
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        buf = message.getBytes();

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        socket.send(packet);

            // get response
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        // display response
        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(packet.getSocketAddress()+" " + received);

        }
    }

}
```

stacktrace after execution gives me :

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.checkAndReturnNativeFD(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
    at snippet.ChatServer$1.run(ChatServer.java:40)
```

I cannot identify the problem. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sendAll` method is closing the socket after every (the first) sent packet.

Comment: fixed that, now I am gettinf a concurrentmodificationexception with the listarray. Working on that now. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, that's a standard problem when you're iterating over a list in one thread and adding to it in another. Make a copy (preferably using Guava `ImmutableList`) and iterate over that instead. The copy operation and the add operation need to be `synchronized`.

Comment: hey, do you think it is advisable to use CopyonWriteArrayList..(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of synchronized() ? I am kinda weak at the synchronize stuff this seems a viable option @chrylis

Comment: @user2535490 No, copy-on-write is designed for situations where shared data structures have very few writes. Yours will have plenty of them, and COW would kill your performance. Depending on the problem you're trying to solve, a thread-safe queue might be a better option; this *looks* like a producer-consumer situation, but that's not clear.

Comment: Okay, I went with the ArrayList and used synchronized in the end. Cheers :D. The copyonwrite structure was memory and time consuming according to what i found on the internet anyway like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the meaning of the `finally` block. It is currently executed in each iteration of sendAll. You are closing the socket for every client when you should be doing it only for the last one.